# Concealing JS/logic from user in HTML page

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I know there's no way to conceal JS loaded into an HTML page from the user, but for the next couple of projects I have lined up (games), this does create quite a problem - there's nothing to stop an intrepid user from simply opening the console up and, say, giving themselves another twenty lives/adding a million to their score.

Code obfuscation would make this harder, but not impossible, and it doesn't seem at all practical to have the stuff which needs protecting running on server/PHP - in any case, any data retrieved could be over-written again. Similarly, one can conceal variables using closures, but the constructor functions are still visible, and thus over-writable.

(I realise the likelihood of this happening in a browser game is low, but I figured the issue worthy of discussion as data security/concealment goes further than games)

I can't use Flash as they'll need to work on mobile devices (applets OOQ for same reason), and I do ideally need to use JS for the engine of one game, as large chunks of the runtime code are dynamically generated/altered.

Does anyone have a practical or ingenious solution for concealing program logic from the end user in a JS/HTML game?

Comment: Sadly, you can't really hide JS... But you CAN make it super annoying for hackers. Have at least 15 different JS files, and spread every tiny bit of code over all of them. Also make all function and variable names alphabetically named with 2 or 3 characters. And use plenty of random arrays. Look at Google's javascript if you need obfuscation ideas...

Comment: I guess that's a solution - if HTML5 games are to replace Flash, it does seem rather a glaring hole!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real solution to this, you can only really deter or slow the user - not stop them.

What I have chosen to do in the past is something like this:

```
(function(){
    var Game = {
        // game object stuff.
    }
    // Game listeners
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        Game.init();
    });
})();
```

The function wrapper hides the Game variable from the global namespace (so in the JavaScript console it isn't as straightforward to go ahead and modify things). Hope this helps!

Comment: That's what I've been doing, again it's technically possible to over-write the function (unlikely, I concede, but more interested in the flaw than the chances of it being exploited in this instance), guess I'll just have to swallow it!

Comment: If you go this route, I would recommend utilizing AMD / Common JS patterns (checkout require.js) to further obfuscate class assignment. Fewer developers will have the experience to extract these values.

Answer (score 1):

Server side validation is the only way to ensure client side integrity.

Sorry :(

Comment: I figured, but even then surely the request/callback can be intercepted and the data changed?

Comment: The data can always be changed on the client side, due to the nature of Javascript. However, if game statistics are exposed to other players, such as high scores or multiplayer, you can still leverage server side validation. Key interactions in the game would need to be verified server side before scores would be saved in the database. These key interactions depend on the type of game you are developing. If you can share a bit more detail (nothing revealing), I can provide an example of how you might validate the interactions.

Answer (score 1):

Joe's got the right idea, here.

Your solution is to run everything inside of closures.

None of the `Game.player.num_lives;` stuff.

```
var Game = (function () {

    var game = {},

        import = function (module_name, module_constructor) {
        },

        public_interface = {
            import : import,
            load   : load,
            start  : start
        };

    return public_interface;
}());

/* player.js */
Game.import("player", function () { /* ... */ });
```

Now other than running `.start();`, there should be NO interaction on the outside of the game.

This makes things much more complicated, in terms of structure, and making sure that each injected object is given access to the other parts that it needs (minimal).

Tampering is now much, much, much harder to accomplish if we're talking single-player.
In terms of multiplayer, this does absolutely nothing for protecting your servers against client-server communication.  Hacking leaderboards, or "auto-firing" and the like, by hand-crafting posts to the server needs to be handled by running the game on the server, and merely accepting and validating client input (and telling the client what happens next in the response).

Comment: Thanks for the help - this is a real pain isn't it?